# How to use JS to open a url link using <DIV> and not text or an image embedded within 'a' tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to open a URL link using DIV tags and nothing else.

So this is my HTML/JavaScript:

```
<div id="divs" onmouseover="newfunction2()"></div>
```

and this is the function:

```
function newfunction2(){
var txt = document.getElementById('divs');
if(document.body.scrollTop >= 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0){
    txt.innerHTML = '<a href="http://www.bbc.com"><div id="divss"></div></a>';
 } else {
     txt.innerHTML = "";
 }}
```

(the id="divs" just positions a display:block and so does id="divss"

I want to click the div id="divss" to open the link?

```js
function newfunction2(){
var txt = document.getElementById('divs');
if(document.body.scrollTop >= 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0){
    txt.innerHTML = '<a href="http://www.bbc.com"><div id="divss"></div></a>';
 } else {
     txt.innerHTML = "";
 }}
```

```css
#divs{
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 18px;
  width:20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

a #divss{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="divs" onmouseover="newfunction2()"></div>
```

Comment: `newfunction2()` will never be called because the `<div>` have nothing inside it and it will not be displayed and can't be hovered

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your div empty, css can come to your rescue.

```js
document.querySelector('#divs').addEventListener('click', e => {
  window.open('http://www.bbc.com', '_blank');  
});
```

```css
#divs {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="divs"/>
```

Try this updated code:

```js
document.querySelector('#divs').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  window.open('http://www.bbc.com', '_blank');  
});
```

Comment: Er...wait a minute...in Firefox it opens an extra webpage tab every time I move off the div and move on it again and click. the function is not ended after I move off the div, I think...

Comment: No that didn't work. the should be a mouseoff function I think

Comment: Is there a conditional statement that could be added to the js? ie. if mouseover div execute function else if mouse off div do nothing?

Comment: share code what you are trying to do, then it will be more clear.

Comment: The code you made Hamza was so close to how I wanted it. I'll try to figure out how it can work properly. If no joy, I'll update code here.

Comment: Okay so I loaded the function using window.onload = function() {new function()}; and it working perfectly...thanks Hamza

Answer (score 0):

> I want to click the div id="divss" to open the link?

add an event listener for the `click` on the `div` and use `window.open` (the second param `'_blank'` is optional to open the link in a new tab.)

```
<div id="divs">

</div>

document.querySelector('#divs').addEventListener('click', e => {
  window.open('http://www.bbc.com', '_blank');  
});
```

Comment: I don't want there to be any text to click (no 'click me'). Just want to click a DIV

Answer (score 0):

Just use `addEventListener` to have your element listen for any click events. When a click is registered then navigate to the new URL:

```js
document.querySelector('#divEl').addEventListener('click', redirect);

function redirect() {
  console.log('Execute the following code:\nwindow.location.assign("http://www.mozilla.org");');
}
```

```html
<div id="divEl">Go to URL</div>
```

I'm not doing the actual redirect in my example, but you just have to use the following line of code for the redirect: `window.location.assign("http://www.mozilla.org");` (or whatever URL you want to direct to).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use anchor tag within the div and this will give you better way to redirect and also add bit css on the div

```
<div id="divs"><a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank"></a></div>
```

css can be

```
#divs{
 cursor:pointer;
}
```